# Can a Nigerian National with a valid Schengen Visa visit Turkey?

Tags: schengen-visas, turkey, nigerian-citizens

I'm a Nigerian passport holder with a valid Schengen Visa. Can I purchase the Turkish E-visa to travel to Turkey?

Comment: Any particular reason for you to think that Schengen visa would have any meaning to the country that's not in Schengen Area?

Comment: @Mołot for citizens of some countries, including Nigeria, Turkish e-visas are granted only to those who have a visa/residence permit from UK/Ireland/USA/Schengen

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a Nigerian citizen becomes eligible for [Turkish e-Visa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/) if he/she is holding a valid Schengen visa. Please note that there are some additional requirements. The website returned the following ones. I chose "Nigeria" and "Ordinary Passport" to see this list.

> You must meet all the requirements listed below in order to obtain an e-Visa. Please confirm that you meet these criteria by clicking the boxes next to them. If you do not meet any of these requirements and you proceed with your application, your e-Visa will be invalid.
>
> - I am travelling for the purposes of tourism or business.
> - I have a valid Supporting Document (Valid visa OR valid residence permit from one of the **Schengen Countries**, USA, UK or Ireland).
>     E-visas are not accepted as supporting documents.
> - I have a round-trip ticket with Turkish Airlines, Pegasus Airlines, Onur Air or Atlasglobal Airlines.
> - I hold a passport valid for at least 6 months from the date I intend to enter Turkey.
> - I can prove that I hold a return ticket, hotel reservation and at least 50 $ per each day of my stay.
> - I confirm that I meet each and every one of the conditions listed above.

This is an additional confirmation from [Turkish MFA](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa).

> **Nigeria:** Ordinary, official/service passport holders are required to
>   have visa to enter Turkey. These passport holders with a valid
>   Schengen members or USA, UK, Ireland visa or residence permit may get
>   their single entry e-Visas valid for one month e-Visas via the website
>   www.evisa.gov.tr, provided that they meet certain conditions.
>
> Diplomatic passport holders are exempted from visa for their travels
>   up to 90 days.